# DataTables remove / hide rows with duplicate information in column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, duplicates

I have a datatable with names of web pages:

```
|ID|Page          |Domain  |
----------------------------
|1 |test.com/page1|test.com|
|2 |test.com/page2|test.com|
|3 |xyz.net/page1 |xyz.net |
|4 |xyz.net/page2 |xyz.net |
```

What I want to do is hide (not group) rows with duplicate domain and display only first result for every domain:

```
|ID|Page          |Domain  |
----------------------------
|1 |test.com/page1|test.com|
|3 |xyz.net/page1 |xyz.net |
```

I know how to [hide rows based on their value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131512/datatables-hide-rows-based-on-hidden-column-value), but I wonder how can I do the above thing.

Do I have to write my own piece of code with a helper map/array, in which i'll store domain that I already displayed? Or is there any smarter way how to do this in datatables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I believe the easiest way is first to locate what duplicates we want to exclude, then use a custom filter to only show those rows which not is excluded.

Loop through all the rows, mark rows where the domain already is present as "excluded" :

```
var domain, domains = []
table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
  domain = this.data().domain;
  if (~domains.indexOf(domain)) {
    this.nodes().to$().attr('excluded', 'true')
  } else {
    domains.push(domain) 
  }
})
```

Then setup a simple custom filter that only makes rows not marked as "excluded" visible :

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
   return table.row(dataIndex).nodes().to$().attr('excluded') != 'true'
})
```

We can always go back to show all rows by

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop()
table.draw()
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w75pdyf9/**

Comment: thank you very much David for great and advice and example

Answer (score 1):

***Using JavaScript dictionary***

```
  var dictionary  = {};
                table = document.getElementById("YourTableID");
                tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
                for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {             
                    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; // `index for filter`        
                    if (dictionary[td.textContent]) {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    } else {
                        seen[td.textContent] = true;
                    }
                }
```